# Dictionary Property in VBA Class

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I have been asked to modify an Excel sheet with some arcaic programming.  I have decided to rewrite it rather then modify all of the many GOTO statments and static arrays.  My background is in C# so it has been a bit of a challenge (note: I am sure the naming convention is bad, I am used to being able to use underscore to define private variables)

I am having trouble inializing an attribute of the type dictionary within a class that I have in a VBA application.

The shortened version of the class looks like this

```
Private pTerminalCode As String
Private pTerminalName As String
...... other attributes
Private pPayRoll As Dictionary

'Propeties
Public Property Get terminalCode() As String
  terminalCode = pTerminalCode
End Property
Public Property Let terminalCode(Value As String)
  pTerminalCode = Value
End Property
....... more properties
Public Property Get headCount() As Dictionary
  headCount = pHeadCount
End Property
Public Property Let headCount(Value As Dictionary)
  pHeadCount = Value
End Property
```

When I try to use the following I get the error "Argument not optional" within the Get property of the headCount() attribute.

```
Private Function PopulateTerminal()
   Dim terminal As clsTerminal
   Set terminal = New clsTerminal

   terminal.terminalCode = "Wil"
   terminal.headCount.Add "Company", 100
 End Function
```

I assume somewhere I need to inialize the dictionary (i.e. = New Dictionary) however I am strugling with where to place it.  In C# I do this in the constructor without issue, not sure what to do here.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in the constructor of the VBA class, like so:-

```
Public Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set myDictionary = New Dictionary
End Sub
```

Don't forget to always use the `Set` keyword when assigning an object reference, e.g.:-

```
Public Property Get Foo() As Dictionary
    Set Foo = myDictionary
End Sub
```

Comment: The set was a good catch, that is where the "Argument not optional" error was comming from, however, I am now receieving "Object Variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: Got it worked out.  Not sure why but if I inialize in the constructor I get the Object Variable error, however if I inialize in the declaration it works.  Thanks for the help

Comment: Ah yes, initializing in the declaration is the other option. Perhaps that's even better as it results in lazy initialization.